# JQuery div follow from top to bottom of section

Tags: jquery, html, css

So I have a div that just has some height width and a background color, I would like this div to start at the top of a section of content and as you scroll down it follows you like a sidebar would and then when you get to the end of the section it stops. Here is my code so far:

```
$('.page-home .showcase').scroll(function() {
    $('.page-home .showcase .left-sidebar').animate({
        top: $(this).scrollTop()
    });
});


.page - home.showcase {
        background - color: #f9f9f9;
        padding: 100 px 0;
    }
    .page - home.showcase.left - sidebar {
        display: block;
        position: absolute;
        width: 15 px;
        height: 350 px;
        background - color: #e84d5b;
        z - index: 999;
    }
    .page - home.showcase.showcase - content h2 {
        font - size: 60 px;
        font - weight: 700;
        text - transform: uppercase;
        color: #000; 
}
.page-home .showcase .showcase-content p {
  font-size: 24px;
  margin-top: 60px;
}
.page-home .showcase .showcase-content a {
  margin-top: 60px;
  font-size: 17px; 
}
.page-home .showcase .showcase-content hr {
  left: 15px;
  position: absolute;
  margin-top: 50px; 
}

<div class="showcase">
    <div class="container-fluid">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="left-sidebar"></div>
            <div class="col-md-5 col-md-offset-2">
                <div class="showcase-content">
                    <h2>AAAA</h2>
                    <p>We’re strategists, producers and doers. Collectively you could call us a design and innovation studio.
                        <br>
                        <br>
                        <span>We love what we do... <strong>uncovering your brand’s potential.</strong></span></p>
                    <a href="#" class="btn btn-custom">Case study</a>
                    <hr>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Im a noob with JQuery so any help is appreciated!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is an idea that you can go off of:

```js
$(function() {
  var $window = $(window),
    $content = $('#content'),
    $aside = $('#aside');

  // Make initial adjustment
  adjustAside();

  // Adjust on scroll event
  $window.scroll(adjustAside);

  function adjustAside() {
    // Bounds relative to viewport
    var $contentRect = $content[0].getBoundingClientRect();

    // Div associated with sidebar has moved up past viewport
    if ($contentRect.top < 0) {
      var $asideHeight = $aside.outerHeight();

      // Move sidebar down as long as it still fits inside associated div
      if ($contentRect.bottom > $asideHeight) {
        $aside.css({
          marginTop: $contentRect.top * -1
        })
      } else {
        $aside.css({
          marginTop: $content.innerHeight() - $asideHeight
        })
      }
    } else {
      // Set sidebar to top of associated div
      $aside.css({
        marginTop: 0
      })
    }
  }
});
```

```css
body {
  height: 2000px;
}
#content {
  border: 1px solid red;
  margin-top: 300px;
  padding-right: 220px;
  position: relative;
}
#aside {
  border: 1px solid green;
  width: 200px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
SCROLL DOWN
<br>.
<br>.
<br>.
<div id="content">
  <div id="aside">I will follow him... follow him wherever he may gooooo</div>
  The rain in spain falls mainly on the plain. The rain in spain falls mainly on the plain. The rain in spain falls mainly on the plain. The rain in spain falls mainly on the plain. The rain in spain falls mainly on the plain. The rain in spain falls mainly
  on the plain. The rain in spain falls mainly on the plain. The rain in spain falls mainly on the plain. The rain in spain falls mainly on the plain. The rain in spain falls mainly on the plain. The rain in spain falls mainly on the plain. The rain in
  spain falls mainly on the plain. The rain in spain falls mainly on the plain. The rain in spain falls mainly on the plain.
</div>

<div>
  The rain in spain falls mainly on the plain. The rain in spain falls mainly on the plain.
</div>
```

Comment: I fixed the issue. The object returned by 'getBoundingClientRect()' doesn't have `x` and `y` properties in Chrome, which is what you are likely using.  I changed the script to use the `top` property instead of `y`, which exists in all browsers.  Try it now.